# How to remove all existing git files so that i can renew my own repository without getting fatal error?

Tags: c, linux, git, version-control, github

I have a git clone of a C project, and on that i have my own customized modules, after final  modification, i want to make my own stable repository as backup in to github. So when i try to add as below, it fails, because in the child directory there are many .git or .gitignore exist:

Example:

```
$ ls -a
/var/tmp/me  << main project
/var/tmp/me/folder/main.c
/var/tmp/me/folder/main.h
/var/tmp/me/folder/etcetc.c
/var/tmp/me/folder/.gitignore
/var/tmp/me/folder/.git
/var/tmp/me/another/.git
/var/tmp/me/another/.gitignore
$ sudo git remote add origin git@github.com:me/my.git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

How do i remove *all* the previous git repository flags? So that i can apply the git remote add origin?

Comment: I don't buy that that's actual `ls -a` output. Perform your Git commands inside the project directory.

Comment: @larsmans: I know ls -a is not that but here again shown same as mentioned above: `$ pwd; /var/tmp/me $ sudo git remote add origin git@github.com:me/my.git fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: That's not surprising since `/var/tmp/me` is not a Git repo; two of its subdirs are. Do you want to merge those into a single repo?

Comment: @larsmans: Yes you are very correct. My subdir's are actually the main application. So i want to make a new repository /var/tmp/me << only. As single repo. How can i do that please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try

```
git submodule add git@github.com:me/submodule.git
```